# Product Category suddenly disappeared from woocommerce admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There were many product categories available but suddenly all categories disappeared from woocommerce admin panel. Category count is still showing there but no categories found. I tried to clear product categories from tables and created new again. But it happened again after some time.

[image]

Comment: First run the WooCommerce data Update. check above WooCommerce notice message

Comment: after update WooCommerce you need to run this for synchronize data

Comment: @AnkurBhadania  How to synchronize woocommerce data?

Comment: Click the button Run Updater in WooCommerce Notice. but first backup database

Comment: @AnkurBhadania I already have done this, but still see same issue.